# TFS 2015 - can I auto-generate tasks for certain work item types

Tags: templates, tfs, customising

In TFS 2015 are using a customised Scrum template for our current projects. For certain work item types, there will **always** be certain tasks that will be added, e.g. `Write test case` and `Test & confirm done`.

Can we customise the project template further so that when a User Story (for example) is added, those tasks will get auto-generated too? How is this done?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add those tasks by using a server event handler for the  WorkItemChangedEventHandler event. You can find [here](http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/04/14/create-a-team-foundation-server-event-handler/) how to write this kind of plugin.

Comment: The new tfsaggregator will support that scenario

Comment: Thanks, this tfsaggregator is a bit beyond me presently, I'll try it out with my tech guys next week.